# Appending to tbody appends to the top?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm getting weird results appending to a tbody. Sometimes it appends to the top, other times both top and bottom.

This jsfiddle shows that appending to a tbody is at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/dxnw34bb/

But on my website, it appends to the top of the table:

http://tx.rxtron.com/restore.php
(change the value on the last input box (storage slots) to 5)

The code on my site is:

```
$('tbody#form').append("<tr class='storage-contents' id='slot-"+i+"'><td>Slot "+(i+1)+":</td> <td>"+ "<button id='potion-"+i+"'>Potion</button>"+ "<button id='ring-"+i+"'>Ring</button>"+ "<button id='wand-"+i+"'>Wand</button> <button id='empty-"+i+"'>Empty</button></td></tr>");
```

Why is it appending the button rows to the top of the table instead of the bottom?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: The HTML seems to be missing from the question. It's very hard to tell why the JS doesn't manipulate HTML in the way you expect when the HTML is missing.

Comment: You should do [basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftx.rxtron.com%2Frestore.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) first though (since fixing the errors there **will** fix the problem you are experiencing).

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure I should post all the html on here, that's why I left a link

Comment: — The question is going to be pretty useless when people come along later, after you've fixed the problem, and can't see the broken code any more. Don't post ALL the HTML. Post enough to reproduce the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok, the `caption` is the problem as stated from others, also you haven't also closed the from tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
As stated from CBroe in the comment the `caption` tag can't be placed inside the table as child.(link by CBroe:[Code Check](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://tx.rxtron.com/restore.php))
Also you haven't closed the `form` tag
The problem is that on your site you have got 2 tbody and the #form is before the one with all the inputs.
From firebug:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="form"> </tbody>
    <caption>Restore Stats</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Storage Slots:</td>
            <td>
            <td class="tip">The size of your storage box</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Under the caption I don't have another tbody like in your example

Comment: Not in your HTML code – but that is what the browser _makes_ of your HTML, when it builds the DOM, _because your HTML is invalid_: `caption` may only be placed as the first child element of a `table`, but you put it into the `tbody` (which makes the browser close the latter implicitly, and open another one after the caption). [Fix your broken HTML code.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://tx.rxtron.com/restore.php)